# Xcode Multiple Commands error, cant figure this one out

Tags: xcode

I tried to delete everything in the DerivedData folder and rebuild, same error. The app will build and run on the device but will not archive to release.

Multiple commands produce '/Users/usr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SoldFor-cfejacqjaocdcgcqzjesxtvjhdxa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/SoldFor/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework':

1. Target 'GoogleUtilities-00567490' has create directory command with output '/Users/usr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SoldFor-cfejacqjaocdcgcqzjesxtvjhdxa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/SoldFor/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework'
2. Target 'GoogleUtilities-df6f21d7' has create directory command with output '/Users/usr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SoldFor-cfejacqjaocdcgcqzjesxtvjhdxa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/SoldFor/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework'

Comment: It sounds like a problem with dependencies.  Do you have pods or something that try to build duplicate frameworks?

Comment: same problem here: Multiple commands produce '/Users/.../phoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework'